# beforeSave not working cakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am struggling a lot with this problem.

My Model Code

```
class User extends AppModel {

App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

$validate   =   array();

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave();
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Controller's save method

```
public function register(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                                        __('registration is successfully completed. you can login now.'), 
                                        'success', 
                                        array(), 
                                        'auth'
                                    );
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(
                                    __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'),
                                       'error'
                                );
    }
    $this->layout = false;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to put the requst data already in create(). Or can you debug if the method is called but the password is nor updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out my file name was incorrect.